# Advices on structure and names for namespaces and classes

Tags: naming, class, namespace

I'm resistant to calling the "main" class the same as the namespace, but I sometimes find myself needing it. Considering I'm using the `Vendor.Namespace.[Subnamespace].Class` formula, imagine this scenario:

```
[MyFramework]
    [Database]
        Database
        Sql
        Schema
        DriverAbstract
        DriverInterface
        [Drivers]
            Mysql
            Postgresql
            Sqlite
```

obs: `[]` are for namespaces, the others are classes.

Now, I could call the `Database` class `Connection` instead, but when I import the namespace `MyFramework.Database` I would only see `Connection` in the code (but connection to what?). Other solution would be calling it `DatabaseConnection`, but is that really necessary? I would like to hear your thoughts and ideas on that problem. Thank you (:

Sidequest: also, what are your thougths on `DriverAbstract` and `DriverInterface`? Should they fit better in the `[Drivers]` namespace? Should I call `DriverAbstract` just `Driver`?

Answer (score 2):

While you haven't specified a language, some of the tips provided for .Net laguages apply to all languages: [Names of Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229026%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

> Do not use the same name for a namespace and a type in that namespace. For example, do not use Debug for a namespace name and also provide a class named Debug in the same namespace. Several compilers require such types to be fully qualified.
>
> Do not introduce generic type names such as Element, Node, Log, and Message. There is a very high probability it would lead to type name conflicts in common scenarios. You should qualify the generic type names (FormElement, XmlNode EventLog, SoapMessage).

If the `Database` class is public, I'd think about naming it *`MyFramework`*`Connection`.  At a minimum I would avoid naming it `Database` due to it conflicting with the namespace.

---

Consider this scenario.

```
namespace Database
{
    public class Database
    {
        public static object Schema { get; private set; }
    }

    public class Schema {
        ...
    }
}
```

What happens when you refer to:

```
Database.Schema
```

Does it return the value of `Schema` from the `Database` class, or does it return the `Schema` type from the `Database` namespace?

Comment: very good advices (: ~ maybe i should name DBConnection then? Or is the full name better? DatabaseConnection...I guess I shouldn't be afraid of long names right? :p

Comment: `DbConnection` is used in `System.Data.Common`.  If someone is using your library alongside other databases, `DbConnection` will be ambiguous.  They will have to fully qualify `System.Data.Common.DbConnection` and `MyFramework.Database.DbConnection`.  It's for you to decide whether this will be an issue.  Don't be afraid of long names.  `MyFrameworkConnection` makes it perfectly clear what the class does.